# C# Call a showdialog inside backgroundworker from a Class library

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, backgroundworker, class-library

I have a class library, in that I have a background worker. I need to show a windows form using showdialog inside the background worker. I tried the below code, the object is getting disposed.

```
private void myBGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

   // non UI works 
       .....


    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.ShowDialog();                // Exception :  Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'form1'.
    String returnstring = form1.GetReturnString();

   // Continue non UI Works
    .....
}
```

I googled, i can call ShowDialog from windows forms app using

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    //my code
});
```

Is it possible to call it from a class library inside a background worker ? If so, How ?

**Edit:**

I found that the object get disposed only when i change a ListBox control values or change any values in the Form, If i didn't make any changes in the Form, ShowDialog works. –  Narayan 42 secs ago   edit

Comment: Your code has no non-UI work, so it shouldn't be in a BGW's `DoWork` handler in the first place.  Just call it directly from the UI thread to begin with instead of going to a background thread just so that you can marshal straight back to the UI thread.

Comment: I found that the object get disposed only when i change a ListBox control values or change any values in the Form, If i didn't make any changes in the Form, ShowDialog works.

Comment: @Servy , Thanks for your comments. Actually i didn't mention the non-ui works which i'm doing inside backgroundworker. I have edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: Actually the problem for me is different, I'm adding dynamic values to the list box inside Form1 constructor. I'm assigning listbox1.ItemSource = listString; //List<String> listString; .  The object gets disposed because of this. Then i added the listbox items as listbox1.Items.add(listString[0]); , Then the GUI has been invoked, Problem Solved.